# Tools for regression testing

Tags: testing, automated-tests, regression-testing

Every time a new version of software is released, we need to do a full run of all the existing test cases. It's very time consuming. Is it possible to find out the ***modified parts*** of the code base and only execute test cases related to those parts. And only conduct regression tests which is affected by those modified parts.

I want to write a tool to for that. And I want it to be as automatic as possible.

It should be not too difficult to do. And only .NET managed code is considered for now. Or is there any exsiting tools for that?

Comment: Really, great! Could you point me some reference? And I will add a TFS tag for this question.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look. And I'd like to see more answers to this question still.

Comment: Very unfortunate, Test Impact Analysis is only availabe with TFS2010, but we are using TFS2008.

Comment: I strongly suggest you to upgrade to TFS2010, writing an impact test analysis tool won't be a easy task. By the way, which kind of test are you talking about? Unit Test, Test Case, ... ?

Comment: Test case. Currently, there're too many test cases and we don't have time to run all of them for every release. I need to figure out the necessary ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to read this [blog post series](http://scrumdod.blogspot.fr/2010/12/tfs-2010-test-impact-analysis-series.html).
You can do Test Impact Analysis with MTM and Test Case but it requires some knowledge to setup and rigor to be able to use it in the real world.